# Do I need to add comma in a sentence joined with "and with that"

Tags: punctuation, commas

User experience design industry evolved and with that the need for consistent design and centralized design rollouts.

OR

User experience design industry evolved and with that, the need for consistent design and centralized design rollouts.

Comment: Yes, the parenthetical expression could use commas to set it off. But the word *that* is referring to what? Commonly, we look at sentences that describe an evolution, say, and think we labeled it an evolution when we didn't. You are calling 'User experience design industry evolved' as *that*, but what is *that*? You actually need "evolved, and with that **change came** the need..."

Comment: It would leave some people commatose, but I'd be inclined to use "... evolved, and, with that, the need ..."

Comment: Or you can just make things easy on yourself and say "User experience design industry evolved which led to the need for consistent design and centralized design rollouts."

Comment: Thank you all! I am still learning to write and blog. I chose to go with @Nosajimiki advice. Sentence is shorter that way.